# Redirect time in codeigniter-3

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i am using codeigniter 3

i am facing when i submit a form, the validate function name shows on the URL then it will redirect the another page.

How can i hide the validate function name in URL while submitting.

Sample Code:-

```
Controller name : user
function name : login
Validate function name : validation
redirect('user/dashboard')
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: either you can give validation function call from login or write validation logic before saving the data

Comment: make your function with private scope.

Comment: you can write validation rules in the same controller where you load the function by specifiying simply `if(isset($this->input->post('submit')){ //perform validation }` so same url comes up on top after validation

Comment: i am asking is 
controller : users

Answer (score 0):

No need separate function for validation, use same controller and function,

```
class user extends CI_Controller
{
   function __construct()
   {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user_model');

    }

    public function login()
   {
      if($this->input->post('act')=="login")
      {
         //write validation here
          if($this->form_validation->run()==true)
          {
             $this->user_model->user_login();

            $this->session->set_flashdata("success","Record inserted successfully");
            redirect(base_url('user/dashboard/'));
          }
       }
    }
}
```